# Windows forms - textbox that accepts specific timestamp format

Tags: c#, windows, forms, maskedtextbox

How can I add  a masked textbox in Windows forms that accepts datetime in the following format:

> 01/01/1993 12:00 AM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way to solove this using [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

```
 dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
 dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm";
```

Best that can be done with MaskedTextbox is by setting following Mask

```
 maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000 00:00 AM"
```

Then again all of the validations have to be hand written  by you.

Comment: You should add \ before A symbol to make it displayable

Comment: A is used as a mask to accept any alphabet in that place. If i make it `\A` I cannot change it to `PM` :)

Comment: How would we be able to display AM or PM?

Answer (score 0):

According MS specification from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx), you cannot specify such format. The most nearest meaning mask for your request would be `00\/00\/0000 90:00 \AM`

Comment: I used to DateTime picker instead with custom format "MMM dd',' yyyy hh':'mm tt"